# Can you improvise a suit of half plate from a suit of plate armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, armor

**If you have a suit of full plate armor, can you improvise or remove some of the armored leg portions to functionally approximate half-plate?**

**Plate armor:**

> Plate consists of shaped, interlocking metal plates to cover the
>   entire body. A suit of plate includes gauntlets, heavy leather boots,
>   a visored helmet, and thick layers of padding underneath the armor.
>   Buckles and straps distribute the weight over the body.

**Half-plate:**

> Half plate consists of shaped metal plates that cover most of the
>   wearer’s body. It does not include leg protection beyond simple
>   greaves that are attached with leather straps.

Now it seems to me that the top half of the armor (from this description, at least) is virtually identical. I suppose most of the question hinges on whether you can fashion greaves (or something functionally similar) to pass for their purpose from a suit of full plate (preferably without any appreciable penalties to AC).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you think "improvise" would mean? Just removing a few pieces by hand? Not strapping certain parts on/down? Cutting bits off? Breaking parts? Taking it to a blacksmith? Forge Cleric Artisan's Blessing?

Comment: What prevents you from selling the full plate for half price and just buying a new set of half plate?  When you brought this up to your DM, what was their response?

Comment: What does your DM say?

Comment: The campaign is a spin on "Conscious objectors who are fleeing a tyrannical crown" so buying and selling anything aren't much of an option at the moment - and the character in question would have previously worn plate but in this case, lost heavy armor proficiency. 

In my game the DM says it's a non-issue - but it made me wonder if this question had ever come up before.

Comment: @MivaScott this is definitely a case where the character - someone who's worn plate previously for months of game time would know far more about hacking his gear than I would.

Comment: How did your character lose this proficiency?

Comment: Midgame respec instead of killing a character off and introducing another. The party - being hunted on all sides - has become justifiably xenophobic.

Comment: "It seems to me that the top half of the armour is virtually identical..." Have you Googled full and half plate?

Comment: Changing and/or recreating your character mid-Campaign is already outside the rules (not a judgement). If your character is just magically a different class/archetype, why didn't their gear change to match the new proficiencies?

Comment: Again, I stated that my DM said the quibble over armor is a non-issue. So I'm not asking for this specific reason - but wanted to know if it had ever come up before. 

(I'd imagine that a feasible way it could come up is if a party finds magical plate but has only med. armor proficiencies in the party.)