# In Adventurers League, can you change Full Plate armour into Half Plate?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, armor, dnd-adventurers-league

Playing in AL my barbarian has acquired a set of adamantine full plate armour. As this prevents him from his rage benefits, I was wondering if I could simply use it as adamantine half plate, using the half plate stats?

From the *Player's Handbook*:

> Plate armour: Plate consists of shaped, interlocking metal plates to cover the entire body. A suit of plate includes gauntlets, heavy leather boots, a visored helmet, and thick layers of padding underneath the armor. Buckles and straps distribute the weight over the body.

> Half plate: Half plate consists of shaped metal plates that cover most of the wearer's body. It does not include leg Protection beyond simple greaves that are attached with leather straps.

Could you simply decide not to wear the whole set?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Mostly duplicate of this question: [Can you improvise a suit of half plate from a suit of plate armor?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156696/38834). But it was closed due to lack of clarity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no official rule that says you can do this.

In a home game, it would be fine.  You'd talk to your DM and explain that you can't wear this armor as a barbarian, but that you'd like to just wear some of it and count is as half plate.  Most reasonable DMs would issue a house rule saying you could wear some of the armor, just as you're suggesting.

However in Adventurers League you can't really do that.  One version of the AL DM rules says:

> **You’re Empowered**. Make decisions about how the
>   group interacts with the adventure; adjust or improvise
>   but maintain the adventure’s spirit. This doesn’t allow
>   you to implement new rules, however.

So the DM is not allowed to let you do this.

I recommend trading the armor away to a character that wears heavy armor.

Answer (score 31):

### Half of a suit of full [plate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_armour) is not a suit of half plate

Full plate armour is the type of armour that stands around in haunted houses - head to toe interlocking and interconnected plates of steel all over the body. The classic chivalric knight.

Half plate is armour predominately for the torso and head and is made that way from the ground up. You don’t get it by taking a suit of full plate and throwing bits away. It developed in response to the rise in firearms and lingered through the Napoleonic period in the armour worn by cuirassiers. It saw a brief revival in the First World War and has come back with new materials as modern body armour.

**However, you are allowed to sell equipment in AL for half list price. Half the value of full plate happens to be exactly what you need to buy half plate.**

This works fine for normal armour but is no good for magic armour which adamantine is. You are allowed to [swap](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/adamantine-armor) magic items  of equivalent rarity (uncommon in this case) with other players if you can find one.